# Cfquery insert unexpected recordcount

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need to get the `recordcount` of the `insert into select` query using cfquery.

While testing with a simple query I'm unable to get the desired result.

I'm always getting the recordcount as 1.

**Code** :

```
<cfquery name="Q_Test" datasource="DATABASE" result="queryresult">
        INSERT INTO GS_TEMP
            SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM) dt
              FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#queryresult#">
```

**Output:**
[image: Insert Query]

Is this expected?

Comment: I've noticed this problem before and never did find the root cause. It does insert all the records it should though.

Comment: @MattBusche : Yes, insert operation does insert all the records though. Strangely, issue is with the `result` object.

Comment: As an aside - your insert will not take into account leap years. If that is an issue then a more robust solution would be: `SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ROWNUM FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ROWNUM >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' YEAR;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of rows then you can do:

**Oracle**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_dates_for_prev_year(
  out_num_rows NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO GS_TEMP
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' YEAR;

  out_num_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
END create_dates_for_prev_year;
/
```

**ColdFusion**

```
<cfscript>
  sp = new StoredProc( dataSource = "DATABASE" );
  sp.setProcedure( "create_dates_for_prev_year" );
  sp.addParam( cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER", type="out", variable="numRows" );
  numRows = sp.execute.getProcOutVariables().numRows;

  writeDump( numRows );
</cfscript>
```

(Not tested the above code but it should be mostly correct)